# Instance variables not available in sub-classes..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, subclass

I've tried removing cache, clean all targets, etc.
Instance variables from my super class are getting highlighted green according to my color scheme, but the compiler then fails saying

```
"score" (or whatever) undeclared"
```

If I have two references in one method, only the first one fails. If I leave them out, or use instance variables from my subclasses header, the app compiles and runs fine.

It was working literally just 2 days ago. I wonder if I accidentally hit a shortcut that turned on some weird setting?

It's running in the 3.2 iPad simulator, if that matters.

It's a weird one.. hope someone has run into this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your instance variables are declared as @private. This means that only that exact class can access them. If you want subclasses to access the ivars directly put @protected above them, eg

```
@protected
id myiVar;
NSString *myStringIVar;
```

Comment: Good idea. Wasn't the case though. Copying the project gave same issue, but copying the code worked.. I'll just chalk this up to "Xcode weirdness"